# How to Deploy Stored Procedures to a Federated Database in SQL Azure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure, azure-sql-database, federation

I am currently working on getting automatic migrations set up to go to a federated database in Azure. I have finally gotten deployment of tables working, but one thing that is concerning for the future is deploying stored procedures.

It appears that when we add a stored procedure, it exists only on whatever part of the federation we were in. So, if I have the data separated out into two databases and deploy the stored procedures to one of the dbs, then it will only be there. **Is there any way to deploy a stored procedure out to every database in a federation that is built into Azure already?**

I did find [a msdn blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/12/29/introduction-to-fan-out-queries-querying-multiple-federation-members-with-federations-in-sql-azure.aspx) about querying from multiple databases and I think that I could modify this to deploy the procedures, but I would rather not implement that in the current migration setup, as I think it would get messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the only way to fan-out your script to create a stored procedure. Similar as what Cihan said in his blog post. But I think you'd better create the tables, procedures and functions, etc. on the first member, before you split. If so the SQL Azure will help you create the members with the procedures.

Comment: That's what I thought. Figured I should try to get a second opinion before trying to shoehorn in that fan out piece in case we need to add stuff later though. Thanks.